# Google search does not show sub-pages from my website

Tags: google

My website appears in Google search, but only the first page. Of course I have sub-pages linked from the first page, but the sub-pages do not show in Google search. Not in Yahoo, not in Bing.

What should I do? It has been three years that sub-pages do not show. (I tried searching site:mydomain.com and pressed 'repeat the search with the omitted results included' link) What would you suspect the reason?

My website addresses were like  xxx.php?yy=zzz etc, etc, so I changed it to /yy/zzz using mod_rewrite.

I thought it might be (X)HTML standard violations, so now I changed it.

I hope Google will soon have my entire website, but I am a little bit pessimistic.

Do you have any thought?

Comment: What's your website address? I could try take a look if any problem sticks out and catch my eye

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your goodwill. Now, at least Google has my pages in its index. So, I guess it's okay now. Perhaps it was sitemap, but I'm not sure. Thanks any way!!

Comment: may be this link will help you
https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check to see if your robots.txt file is accidentally blocking access to those files. [Google Webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/siteoverview?hl=en) can help you with this.
- Submit an XML sitemap ([although it may not necessarily help](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox))
- Submit some of your more important sub pages directly to [Google](http://www.google.com/addurl.html) and [Bing](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/SubmitSitePage.aspx)
- Get incoming links from other sites directly to your inner pages

Answer (score 1):

Add your site to Google Webmaster Tools. Under Health, check for crawl errors, blocked URLs and malware. All potentially problematic for indexing inner pages.

Answer (score 0):

By sub-pages, I guess you mean the links shown below some sites in Google search results which are called Sitelinks.

Sitelinks are **completely automated** & based on Google's algorithms. To get Sitelinks for a site it helps to have a well-structured website.

[As per Googler Maile Ohye](http://groups.google.com/group/Google_Webmaster_Help-Tools/browse_thread/thread/63b915eed3386a60?pli=1),

> Sitelinks are often produced when
>   there's a high probability that the
>   site is the top match for the user's
>   query. In other words, to have
>   sitelinks ... you'll probably need to
>   be the definitive first result

Comment: I think they meant inner page, i.e. pages that are not their home page.

Comment: Yes, I meant inner pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when trying site:centaminute.com, it only showed five pages. I went into Google Webmaster Tools and I manually submitted all pages that were not indexed (now there are 17 in total). They appeared in the results immediately afterwards.
This solution is practical only for a pretty small number of pages though.